# php - how to test if a string contains an uppercase word?

Tags: php, match

$string = "ttest test NEEDLE haystack";

How do I match to see if the $string contains the uppercase word "NEEDLE"?

I have been using `if ( stristr($string, 'NEEDLE') === TRUE )` but it is not case sensitive.

TIA

Comment: That's what the **i** in the function name means: case-insensitive.

Answer (score 3):

Just use *strstr* instead

```
if ( strstr($string, 'NEEDLE') === TRUE )
```

However: this will still fail, because the *strstr* function and *stristr* return a string and only a boolean, if the sub-string is not found. You could also use strpos instead, which returns either an integer *or* false, if the substring was not found:

```
if (strpos($string, 'NEEDLE') !== false)
```

Comment: Thanks Harald for the quick response.

Comment: @harald:  `strstr()` and `stristr()` do return a boolean on failure, so `strstr($string, 'NEEDLE') !== FALSE` would work just fine.  You might want to reword that part of your answer to be less confusing for newcomers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`strstr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php), which is the case-sensitive version of `stristr`:

```
if ( strstr($string, 'NEEDLE') !== false ) {
  // do something...
}
```

Note that `strstr` documentation recommends using [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) if you just only want to know if the needle occurs within the haystack.

If you need more complex comparisons you could also use [`preg_match`](http://%60preg_match%60), but in this case I think `strstr` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use the case-sensitive [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
if (strpos($string, 'NEEDLE') !== false)
```

[`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) would work as well here, but unnecessarily returns the rest of the string instead of just a short indication where it has been matched. Note that neither of `stristr`, `strstr`, or `strpos` ever return `true`.

Comment: Thanks philhag, it is late and I skipped right over the strstr when I looked up stristr.  strpos seems like a better alternative for some of my other matches.